# How can I add a back button to a map redirect ionic?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, ionic-framework

I am running an ionic google map app.
The problem I have is googles terms and condition at the bottom right. I want to show the terms and conditions but when I am running the app and click on terms and conditions another window is opened, essentially making my app disappear.

How can I click on terms and conditions but make it be inside a frame?

http://codepen.io/leetcat/pen/GZrLRN

The index.html:

```
<html ng-app="ionic.example">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">

    <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- google maps javascript -->
    <script src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB16sGmIekuGIvYOfNoW9T44377IU2d2Es&sensor=true"></script>

  </head>
  <body ng-controller="MapCtrl">
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-dark" >
      <h1 class="title">Map</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
      <div id="map" data-tap-disabled="true"></div>
    </ion-content>
  </body>
</html>
```

The app.js

```
angular.module('ionic.example', ['ionic'])    
    .controller('MapCtrl', function($scope, $ionicLoading, $compile) {
      function initialize() {
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(43.07493,-89.381388);

        var mapOptions = {
          center: myLatlng,
          zoom: 16,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
            mapOptions);          
        $scope.map = map;
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    });
```

When terms and conditions is clicked a new page is opened. I want it opened in a frame so I can click back. In an iOS app there is no way to click back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this function to your app.js file:

```
function changeTermsOfUseClick() {
  var a = document.getElementsByClassName('gmnoprint').item(1).lastChild.lastChild;
  a.setAttribute('href',"#/html/redirect/here");
  a.removeAttribute('target');
};
```

and add this line to your initialize function:

```
$scope.initialize = function() {
  google.maps.event.addListenerOnce($scope.map, 'tilesloaded', changeTermsOfUseClick);
};
```

Once the map has loaded, changeTermsOfUseClick() is called, and the element whose href we want to change exists, so you can then point it to wherever in your app you want, change this `#/html/redirect/here`.

Make sure you also don't remove it without showing it, that would be illegal.